# How do I unlock the lock at the end of Sputnik Eyes?

Tags: ios, sputnik-eyes

[image: locked]

After the letter planets, there is a locked planet. I finished the last planet but it is still locked. Do I need perfect completions? To finish all levels?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Finish each level with all 3 emblems.